# This code is running well for upload and extension check but not when file already exists

Tags: php

The page starts from index but other things are running well so the page starts from upload here. The code is only deleting the file in the case of file already exists.i'm new to php. Is there something wrong with the code??

> upload.php

```
<?php
        if($action=="upload"){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("File Uploaded")';
        echo '</script>';
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        if($action=="error"){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Please Upload only (xls,pdf,doc)files.")';
        echo '</script>';
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        if($action=="error_dct"){
        //var_dump($name);
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'var x=confirm("Selected file already exists.");';
        echo 'if(x==true)';
        echo '{';
        $path="uploads_masterdata/".$name;
        unlink($path);
        //var_dump($tmp);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);
        echo '}';
        echo '</script>';
        } 
        ?>



    <?php
            define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
            define('ROOT_URL', substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, - (strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) - strlen(ROOT_DIR))));
            session_start();
            //$errors= array();
            $expensions= array(".xls",".xlsx",".doc",".docx",".pdf"); 
             //$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['userFile']['name'])));
             $file_name = $_FILES['userFile']['name'];
              $file_ext=substr($file_name, strrpos($file_name, '.'));
              var_dump($file_ext);
            $info = pathinfo($_FILES['userFile']['name']);
            $tmp=$_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'];
            $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
            $newname = $file_name; 
            if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
                     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a .xls file.";
                     header("location: masterdata.php?action=error&name=$newname&fe=$file_ext");
                  }

             if(file_exists(ROOT_DIR."/uploads/uploads_masterdata/".$_FILES['userFile']['name']))
            {
            $errors[]="file already exists";
            header("location: masterdata.php?action=error_dct&tmp=$tmp&name=$newname");
            }    
                  if(empty($errors)==true){

             $target = ROOT_DIR.'/uploads/uploads_masterdata/'.$newname;
             //$target = 'uploads_masterdata/'.$newname;
             //move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $target);
             move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $target);
            header("location: masterdata.php?action=upload");
                  }
                  else{
                     //print_r($errors);
                     //header("location: masterdata.php");

                  }
            ?>
```

> index.php

```
<?php
if($action=="upload"){
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("File Uploaded")';
echo '</script>';
}
?>
<?php
if($action=="error"){
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Please Upload only (xls,pdf,doc)files.")';
echo '</script>';
}
?>
<?php
if($action=="error_dct"){
//var_dump($name);
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'var x=confirm("Selected file already exists.");';
echo 'if(x==true)';
echo '{';
$path="uploads_masterdata/".$name;
unlink($path);
//var_dump($tmp);
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);
echo '}';
echo '</script>';
} 
?>
```

Comment: Just always try to delete the target file prior to moving the temporary, uploaded file. Doesn't do any harm, if the file does not exist yet.

Comment: And a general hint: filtering file uploads by "file name extension" is more or less without sense. Either you validate the _content_ of the files, or you don't. But every noob can change a "file name extension" to whatever he likes. Such "file name extensions" are totally overrated. Intelligent systems do not rely on them any more (actually since the late 1980th...).

Comment: thanks i will try to implement these from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php use use [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check file is exist or not

```
 if (file_exists($path)) {// check file exist or not
    unlink($path);// if exist then delete it
 }
 move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);// upload file
```

Comment: i'm checking this in the upload.php file. Do i have to recheck in index.php to upload and replace the file in the directory??

Comment: when ever you upload the file into directory you can check file exist or not.

Comment: its still deleting the file not uploading again

Comment: it will delete your old file and upload your new file

Comment: the older file is deleted but new file is not uploaded

Comment: can $tmp be causing this? i have checked all other thing that might have affected my code.

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` and check the value of it

Comment: string(5) ".docx" Array ( [userFile] => Array ( [name] => New Microsoft Word Document.docx [type] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpB8CE.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 12175 ) )